# How to calculate the sum of row heights for filtered rows

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, vba

**Background:**
I have a sheet that pulls data from a database to create product labels (using index-match lookup formulas). The sheet has a macro I recorded which filters out the blank rows and autofits the remaining rows. (I'm not very familiar with VBA, so please pardon my ignorance)

**Worksheet:**
The data populates in two columns (B and C) and 25 rows. I need help to create a macro which will complete all of these tasks once a product number is entered; filter out the blank rows and autofit the remaining rows, measure the row height for each of the remaining rows, and get the combined total for the row heights to appear (preferably in cell B2). (i.e. "Row Heights: 64")

Any and all help is appreciated and thank you in advance!

Comment: Do you want inches on the **screen** or inches in a **printout** ??

Comment: I am unclear as to what you mean. I apologize if I misstated anything, but I do not need inches at all; just the combined total of all of the row heights remaining after the blank rows have been filtered out.

Answer (score 2):

With filtered data like:

[image]

Code like:

```
Sub TotalHeight()
   Dim HowTall As Long
   Dim Kount As Long
   HowTall = 0
   Kount = 0

   For i = 2 To 25
      Set r = Cells(i, "A").EntireRow
      If Not r.Hidden Then
         HowTall = HowTall + r.RowHeight
         Kount = Kount + 1
      End If
   Next i

   MsgBox Kount & vbCrLf & HowTall
End Sub
```

Will tell you the number of visible rows and the total height of those rows.

***NOTE:***

The unit of height is a **point**, were each point is 0.013888889 inches *(at 100% zoom).  This assumes that you are not using the jumbotron as a monitor.*

Comment: Hm, yeah I was thinking the question was asking for count, but (not tested) it looks like yours covers both.

Comment: @Raystafarian  I began thinking exactly like you.

Comment: What are the units on `rowheight`? Not pixels..

Comment: It works perfectly, but I forgot ONE thing! haha

I actually need the count to start at row 4, as rows 1-3 have headings in them.

How would I adjust this code to fit what I need?


Again...your help is sincerely appreciated!

Comment: @C.Conklin Change `For i = 2 To 25` to `For i = 4 To 25`

Comment: @C.Conklin  Change the single line `For i=2 to 25` to reflect your actual data rows that may be either hidden/visible

Comment: @C.Conklin the big question: do you need the height for exactly the same cells you need to count?

Answer (score 1):

To get the height/count in a variable, fast and easy way just put in your module:

```
Public Function getHeight(rng As Range) As Long
  getHeight = rng.Height
End Function

Public Function getCount(rng As Range) As Long
  getCount = rng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Rows.Count
End Function
```

then simply put in the cell you want the output `=getCount(B4:B25)&" "&getHeight(B2:B25)/96` to get the count and height... but keep in mind that the ppi changes with your settings, resolution and size of the monitor (so you may need to get the real ppi and change the `/96`, but there tons of fast ways to do that... just look here or use google)

For the setting of the filter and auto-height the just "record macro" is a perfect start, now you need to set the filter in a variable way. To get the variable filter, just record while changing it and then replace the filtervalue with `Range("A1").Value` (change A1 to whatever cell you want to use as a filter)

If you still run into problems doing it, just ask at StackOverflow (but you need to show code of what you allready have or they may get mad) :P